# creating a legend with d3.js

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I feel like I am being inefficient here. I am trying to create a legend from an array and it seems like i am writing too much to do this. Can someone tell me if it can be optimized?

http://jsbin.com/foqesivice/edit?js,console,output

```
var data = [
    {name: "AnotherLong"},
    {name: "BigData"},
    {name: "What"},
    {name: "Something"},
    {name: "Smalls"}
];

var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10};

var color = d3.scale.category20c();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 400 - margin.left - margin.right)
  .attr("height", 1000 - margin.top - margin.bottom)

var g = svg.selectAll(".row")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("svg:g")

var rectangles = g.selectAll(".cell")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("svg:rect")
  .attr("width", 19)
  .attr("height", 19)
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; })
  .style("fill", function(d, i){return color(i);})

var text = g.selectAll(".text")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("svg:text")
  .attr("x", 24)
  .attr("y", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; })
  .text(function(d){return d.name;})
```

EDIT:

Another thing that bothers me. It seems like my styling is all BOLD for some reason. I haven't defined any styles. Is that default behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MatthewWilcoxson's answer is good, but here's a more `d3` specific re-write.  Essentially, don't double-bind the data, keep the `g`, bind on it, position that and add the `rect` and `text` to it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var data = [{
      name: "AnotherLong"
    }, {
      name: "BigData"
    }, {
      name: "What"
    }, {
      name: "Something"
    }, {
      name: "Smalls"
    }];

    var margin = {
      top: 10,
      right: 10,
      bottom: 10,
      left: 10
    };

    var color = d3.scale.category20c(),
      cellDim = 19;

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", 400 - margin.left - margin.right)
      .attr("height", 1000 - margin.top - margin.bottom);

    var g = svg.selectAll(".row")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
        return "translate(" + (0) + "," + ((cellDim + 1) * i) + ")"
      });

    g.append("svg:rect")
      .attr("width", cellDim)
      .attr("height", cellDim)
      .style("fill", function(d, i) {
        return color(i);
      });

    g.append("text")
      .attr("dy", "1em")
      .attr("dx", cellDim + 2)
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      });
      
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, your answer seems better to me a looks more like things that I have been working on with d3. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

First, move all the measurements and values to the top of the file and reference them (this just makes things more readable)

```
var legend_row_height = 50;
```

You don't need to create the `g` elements. Just position the rectangles and text with `x,y` attributes instead of translations:

```
.attr("y", function(d,i){return legend_row_height * i;})
```

And move your styling into CSS. This is most easily achieved by setting classes on the objects:

```
.classed("squares", 1)
```

then adding CSS :

```
.squares {
   stroke: white;
}
```

Comment: Indeed sir, you are right on all accounts. I got rid of the `g` creation as well as used the `attr("y")` per your suggestion. Also, removing the `g` block seems to have fixed the "bold" effect.